# How i can valid number only without character by php regular expression

Tags: php

How i can valid number only without character by php regular expression

Comment: What kind of number? Positive integer only? Floating point? Scientific notation?

Answer (score 2):

```
if( filter_var("32", FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) !== false) {
    echo "Valid number";
}

if( filter_var("ab", FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) === false) {
    echo "Invalid Number";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!preg_match("/^([0-9]{1,6})$/", $variable) ¦¦ (is_numeric($variable) != 1))
{
echo ("This is not a valid entry");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ctype_digit()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) if you want to allow only zero or positive integers (without a sign)

Answer (score 0):

Why regex? Use is_numeric() function.